# Avoid suppressing "deprecated" in the replacing class due to Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc, deprecated, deprecation-warning

I have an old class which I have made it deprecated with `@Deprecated` annotation. At the same time, I have made another class that is supposed to replace that deprecated class.

In that new class' Javadoc, I have mentioned that it is meant to replace the deprecated class. This causes the deprecated class to be imported, and gave me the deprecated warning. To remove the warning, I have to use `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` annotation. The result is that my new class looks like it is using something deprecated.

Example:

```
/**
 * Deprecated class.
 * @deprecated Replaced by @{link ReplacingClass}
 */
@Deprecated 
public class DeprecatedClass {}
```

The replacing class:

```
import com.test.example.DeprecatedClass;

/**
 * This class replaces the deprecated class @{link DeprecatedClass}
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class ReplacingClass {}
```

What can I do to prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *have* to import the class to reference it in the Javadoc. You have two options for referencing a class. You can either use the fully qualified class name, or you can use the simple class name if the class is in the search space:

> 1. the current class or interface
> 2. any enclosing classes and interfaces, searching closest first
> 3. any superclasses and superinterfaces, searching closest first
> 4. the current package
> 5. any imported packages, classes and interfaces, searching in the order of the import statement
>
> [Search order for `@See`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#seesearchorder)

In your case, importing (5) would cause a deprecation warning, so you can just use the fully-qualified class name of the deprecated class:

```
/**
 * This class replaces the deprecated class @{link com.test.example.DeprecatedClass}
 */
public class ReplacingClass {}
```

Or if the two classes are in the same package, you just need to remove the `import` statement.